# How to move the position of Data Labels outside the Radar Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to move the data labels of the Radar Chart outside.

So far, these are the codes that i have tried to move labels:

```
            rdrOpportunities.Series["Series1"]["RadarDrawingStyle"] = "Area";
            rdrOpportunities.Series["Series1"]["AreaDrawingStyle"] = "Circle";
            rdrOpportunities.Series["Series1"]["CircularLabelStyle"] = "Circular";
            rdrOpportunities.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 1;

            rdrOpportunities.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
            rdrOpportunities.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
            rdrOpportunities.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
            rdrOpportunities.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
```

Please help :( 
Thankyou in advance for answering my question :)

[This is my Radar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr6CK.png)

[This is the Radar Chart that i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK6kk.png)

[This is my Radar Chart when Gridlines are Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnrYM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct approach is to set a suitable `SmartLabelStyle` for your `Series s`:

```
s.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
s.SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
```

But, looking at the size of your label texts this will not do, as there is not enough space on the outside.

You can then try to reduce the size of the `InnerPlotPosition` of your `ChartArea ca`, like so:

```
ca.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(x, y, w, h);
```

Where the numbers are in percent (!!) of the chart. (0,0,100,100) would fill the whole chart, leaving no room for axes, labels, legends etc..

Depending on the details you will want to leave some room on all sides. Leaving 10% on all sides would use (10, 10, 80, 80). You may have to make the plot area a lot smaller than that, maybe (60,60) or less.. This does take some trial and error..

Note that while this takes the labels somewhat further to the outside, they still are basically inside..

Comment: My chart size changed but the labels are not aligned with axis gridlines :(

Comment: Yes. Your label texts are really too large. Try to break them down to multiple lines by inserting one or more newlines charcters ('\n') !

Comment: Thank you TaW, but is it not possible to do a radar chart like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK6kk.png                          :((((((((((((

Comment: Well, you can do that, but I don't know how to make the labels move outside like they do so easily in aPie chart. You can __replace the Labels by Annotations__, which can be placed freely or anchored in a somewhat flexible way..

Comment: Even though I change the values into single character still the labels are inside the grid line. https://imgur.com/deitDoa